Counter metric of Micrometer in Prometheus using Spring Boot 3
I have just started using Micrometer / Prometheus / Grafana in my SpringBoot 3 app for observability. I have the required dependencies in my pom and want to find the total number of hits to a API. This is what I tried, but in Prometheus UI at http://localhost:9090/ I am not seeing either of the 2 variables getMoviesOfDirector.count or getMoviesOfDirector. Requesting to please guide on how to get the total API hits and which approach.
Approrach 1
 @Counted(value = "getMoviesOfDirector.count", description = "getMoviesOfDirector count")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getMoviesOfDirector(...)

Approrach 2
 //Counter metric
        Counter counter = Counter.builder("getMoviesOfDirector")
                .description("a number of requests to /getMoviesOfDirector endpoint")
                .register(meterRegistry);
        counter.increment();



Spring Boot supports this out of the box, you should see counters for your controller endpoints:
http_server_requests_seconds_count{..., uri="/getMoviesOfDirector"} 1.0

You don't need to use @Counted on top of this.
Also, depending on which version of Boot 3.x you are using you might need to create a CountedAspect @Bean, if you upgrade to Boot 3.3.x, that bean will be created for you.
Another tip: Prometheus uses underscore (_) in its naming convention and Micrometer support this so test.counter in Micrometer will be test_counter_total on Prometheus side.
